# How to convert that page to a wordpress template?

Tags: theme-development, themes, javascript, customization

Couple of days I am trying to integrate [THAT](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/05/23/fresh-sliding-thumbnails-gallery-with-jquery-php) page in wordpress. I converted it to wordpress theme but can't make the images to loads. All I see is the loading circle. I changed the path in javascript that call the ajax file:

```
$.get('http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/two/ajax/thumbs.php?album='+album,function(data){
```

but no result.

I changed even the paths in thumbs.php (example from ../thumbs to full path or with blog_info command )...and again-no result.

Any ideas what else I have to change? I deactivated all plugins, but the site still doesn't work.

I would be very grateful if you help me.

p.s.sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i found the answer:
In thumbs.php change `../images` and `../thumbs` to `../wp-content/themes/YOURTHEMENAME/images`, `../wp-content/themes/YOURTHEMENAME/thumbs`. Same in js.